# using input from file in subprocess.call doesnt work while os.system does

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to create a python3 wrapper for a very old FORTRAN program. Essentially I need to run the program and direct input from a file to the program like this (from the command line).

```
programname < input.txt
```

this works without issue. When I try to do it in python os.system works but subprocess.call does not. When I use subprocess.call I get stuck and the program just sits there waiting for input even though it should already have it.

Why not then just use os.system? I need to have an execution time limit. Sometimes the FORTRAN code gets stuck internally and will just sit there. If its not done in 5 seconds I need it to just be killed. As I understand it os.system cannot enforce a limit but subprocess.call can, so that is what I am chasing.

I have recreated this using a python program as a surrogate for the FORTRAN program. Here is the code for this (pythonInput.py):

```
some_input = input("Enter some input: ") 
print(some_input)
```

Then create an input file with anything, this is what I used (input.txt)

```
RealName
```

From the command line this works without issue:

```
python pythonInput.py < input.txt
```

Returns:

```
[khoopes@computer ~]$ python pythonInput.py < input.txt
Enter some input: RealName
[khoopes@computer ~]$
```

But when I make another script that uses python to call the other python program, it subprocess.call doesnt work, here is the code for that (pythonRunTester.py):

```
import subprocess
import os
os.system('python pythonInput.py < input.txt')
subprocess.call(['python', 'pythonInput.py', '<', 'input.txt'])
```

Returns:

```
[khoopes@computer ~]$ python pythonRunTester.py
Enter some input: RealName
Enter some input:
```

the os.system works, but the subprocess.call does not, it just hangs there waiting. I have tried having it use the shell=True flag like this:

```
import subprocess
import os
os.system('python pythonInput.py < input.txt')
subprocess.call(['python', 'pythonInput.py', '<', 'input.txt'], shell=True)
```

which returns

```
[khoopes@computer ~]$ python pythonRunTester.py
Enter some input: RealName
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug  7 2019, 17:28:10)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas how I could get this to work using subprocess.call or alternatively, some other way I could enforce an execution time using os.system?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

you need to write the whole command without list:

```
subprocess.call('python pythonInput.py < input.txt', shell=True)
```

this will work

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to @LinPy answer you can pass the stdin as argument to `call()`:

```
x = subprocess.call(['python', 'pythonInput.py'], stdin=open("/tmp/test.txt"))
```